# What does it mean when a Pokéstop has a white ring around it?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was walking around when I noticed that some Pokéstops have a small white ring around them.

What is the meaning of the white ring?

[image: Pokestops with White Rings]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That means you haven't spun that pokestop since [Update 0.67.1/1.37.1](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-062017).  It goes away the first time you spin it.  You get a little bonus for doing so; one extra item, to give you some incentive to go to new places.

Comment: You beat me to it and had a link to back it up, I concede. :P

Comment: Based on personal experience, you also get an extra 200xp for visiting a new Pokéstop

Answer (score -5):

Based on the wording of the latest update notes the ring is an "Added visual indicator to unvisited PokéStops", meaning their current form is likely a glitch that will eventually only display stops you've never spun before. However the current blue for ready to spin and purple for recharging is extremely frustrating for colorblind players, and if the current form of the indicator were kept to any degree, it would go a long way towards improving the accessibility of the game.

Comment: Don't add fake answers, this would mistaken the original question author.

Comment: There is nothing in the question mentioning color. Arqade is not for UX discussions, it's for videogame answers. This is completely offtopic.